Calling iconv_open in ios17 takes more than 300 milliseconds
After updating to iOS17, I found that calling iconv_open takes between 300 and 400 milliseconds.
On iOS15 it only takes a few milliseconds.
Print _LIBICONV_VERSION and find that the iconv versions of iOS15 and iOS17 are both 1.11.
Does anyone know why this is?
The character sets I use are UNICODEBIG, GB18030, and UTF-8, so I will call iconv_open("GB18030", "UTF-8") or iconv_open("UNICODEBIG", "UTF-8").
